# How strong is the religious connotation of "belief"?

Tags: meaning, connotation

The verb "to believe" has a very weak religious connotation: it *can* mean "to believe in God" or "to believe that God can work wonders", but it most oftenly is used in a general context, concerning all kinds of things and facts.

Exactly the same holds for the German verb "glauben".

But in German the **noun** "Glauben" is more often than not used in a somehow religious context and thus has a rather strong religious connotation.

Does the same hold for the English noun "belief"? I suppose not, but I am not a native speaker and unable to "hear" the nuances.

If you are both an Englisch and a German native speaker: Do you know of a German equivalent to the neutral "belief".

(Note that the German words "wissen" and "Wissen" are both connotationally neutral, just like English "to know" and "knowledge".)

Comment: I am afraid I don't know any German, but in English *belief* is equally weak as a noun as it is as a verb. People often say things like *It's my belief that the meeting is on Wednesday*. Even when used in a religious context it does not necessarily connote any deeply held faith or commitment.

Comment: @WS2 I don't agree with all you say here. While 'belief' _is_ often – perhaps usually – matched with mental assent rather than an active faith, I believe the religious (though that in itself is an ill-defined term) connotation is very strong outside set expressions like the one you select.

Comment: Thanks. This means that a "belief system" is a network of things and facts (in) which I do believe. (In German the term "Glaubenssystem" sounds strange, it would have to do with church and religion.)

Comment: @Edwin: But you *can* easily use "belief" in quite different contexts (that have nothing to do with faith). My claim is that it's not so usual in German. And WS2 just said, that "belief" in a religious context does not *necessarily* connote faith.

Comment: We're talking about connotations here. Of course you can use _belief_ in a way less likely to trigger thoughts of the religious connection. But with no context, 'The beliefs of ...' will always induce expectations of religion or isms. For instance, [this article on 'The beliefs of Henry VIII'](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/tudor-england/the-beliefs-of-henry-viii/) isn't going to deal with his views on the possibility of bridging the Channel.

Comment: To be honest, I doubt that. Because the concept of a "belief network" which is a synonym of a "Bayesian network" has nothing to with religion or isms. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network)

Comment: I would venture that "beliefs" in the plural is rarely used outside of a religious context.  Talking about someone's "beliefs" doesn't refer to them believing a meeting is on wednesday, but their core, usually religious (or perhaps other deeply held ideological) beliefs.

Comment: Then I don't understand why "belief networks" are so heavily investigated. Is it all about religion?

Comment: "Belief" certainly has a gradient of meanings. A father can believe in his daughter - he knows she will do well. A person can believe in a fundamental principle that defines their life. I can believe a lie is true. I am reminded of a Bible verse: James 2:19: You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that--and shudder. Here in Koine Greek, "believe" appears to have a variety of meanings that translates very well to how English speakers use it. Do you believe, or do you **believe**?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't entirely disagree with you here, Edwin. You will see that I said "it does not *necessarily* connote any deeply-held faith..." Context is everything. *My wife is a believer in roast dinners on Sundays*. But if one begins *Cranmer's beliefs were central to the Elizabethan religious settlement* then *belief* takes on an altogether different sense. All I wanted to get across in reply to the OP's question is that *belief* belongs with the sublime, the ridiculous, and everything in between, in English. I've no idea how this compares to *glauben*.

Comment: @WS2 Note the difference between the strengths of the connotations of 'believe' and (especially not in a fixed expression, and especially when in the plural) 'belief'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* that Einstein's Theory of Relativity is essentially correct.  Note that I do not *know* it to be correct -- maybe ten people on Earth fully understand the theory, and even they would likely admit that there may be further as yet unknown details that would slightly modify the theory.

Some argue that assuming something is true without fully understanding it, and without a rigorous scientific/mathematical proof of it's validity implies some degree of *faith*.  In this sense, virtually everything one *believes* implies they have *faith* in that thing, to some degree, but some ideas demand more *faith* than others (as they have less of a scientific/mathematical foundation).

I *believe* the sun will rise this morning (though it's certainly taking its own sweet time this time of year).  But this *belief* is based on an untold amount of experience and information.  *Believing* in a god, on the other hand, generally has little if any "hard" evidence to back it up, so the degree of *faith* required is much larger.

Generally we say we *believe* something when we do not have rigorous proof of it (it's not quite a "fact"), but we feel reasonably confident of it.  Only if that *belief* is based largely on *faith* (rather than personal experience or other reasonably trustworthy information) does it take on a religious connotation.  (But note that this definition of "religious" would apply to many political theories and medical doctrines, in addition to theories of a supernatural world.)

Comment: This explains quite well the difference between knowledge, belief and faith. Interestingly enough "belief" in German is "Glauben" and "faith" is "Glaube". This makes the distinction more difficult in German.

Comment: The words 'believe' and 'belief' (and especially 'beliefs') have very different connotational leanings.

Comment: If this is so, then it is like in the German language. I believed (smiley) that it was *not* so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I agree that there is a specific sense of "belief" (and which is, as you say, stronger when used in the plural) that implies "faith", but the word can also be used in the secular sense.

Comment: But the question asks about connotations, not the different denotations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But connotation is highly dependent on context.

Comment: And here, a large part of that context is whether 'believe' or 'belief' is used, and whether a focusing modifier like 'belief in himself' is used

Answer (score 1):

"Belief" in modern English is a fuzzy word; more often than not, it's a way of expressing a firm opinion, and has nothing to do with religion.

"I believe in one God" = "I have a monotheistic religious faith"

vs.

"I believe the mayor" = "My opinion is that the mayor is telling the truth" (as opposed to other people)

"I believe in the mayor" = "My opinion is that the mayor is a good person" or "My opinion is that the mayor's platform is a good one for the city" or "My opinion is that the mayor is doing a good job"

"I believe in the US Constitution" = "My opinion is that the US Constitution is a good thing"

Comment: Great answer. But why don't you add: "I believe that the next US president will..." (not "believe *him*" or "believe *in* him" but "believe *that* he ..."

Comment: Yes, that's also an example - that's a more straightforward, traditional use of "believe".  "I believe that (something in the future)" = "I predict that ..."

Comment: But the traditional use is exactly the one I have in focus!

Comment: I could also say "I believe that the next US president is in fact a not so bad guy".

Comment: @HansStricker  Sorry, your question was "does English belief = German glauben as far as religious connotations go?".  My answer is, "English belief is broader than just religion".  Verb & noun in English have the same breadth.  "I believe in X" = "My belief is that X"